# Tinker not debugging with Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I am using Laravel dusk and I read the following article
https://medium.com/@icheko/laravel-dusk-tinker-79a1bcff03cd

Explaining you can use
tinker() to Debug issue with Laravel Dusk
however when I run the following code:

```
public function testTinker()
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $browser->visit('https://www.google.com')
            ->pause(3000);

        $browser->tinker();
    });
}
```

It seems like Dusk dose not stop and allow me to debug.

I am using Laravel with Windows 10.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of [the article you linked](https://medium.com/@icheko/laravel-dusk-tinker-79a1bcff03cd), it says:

> Update: Looks like this only works for Mac —
>
> https://github.com/laravel/dusk/pull/266

I believe the relevant issue is actually https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/276, which says that:

> Warning: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.

Comment: How can Windows users debug properly Dusk?